# 500 server error while accessing /crx/de/replication.jsp in CRXDE Lite in AEM

Tags: java, aem

A new AEM 6.1 SP2 author is recently installed.

In CRXDE, the replication tab reports 500 error as shown below. btw, the replication from content, dam or tree activation works fine.

[image]

==error log==

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicationStatusImpl.isPending(ReplicationStatusImpl.java:106)
    at com.day.crx.delite.impl.servlets.ReplicationServlet.doGet(ReplicationServlet.java:103)
    at com.day.crx.delite.impl.servlets.ReplicationServlet.doService(ReplicationServlet.java:54)
    at com.day.crx.delite.impl.AbstractServlet.service(AbstractServlet.java:52)
    at com.day.crx.delite.impl.MainServlet.doService(MainServlet.java:129)
    at com.day.crx.delite.impl.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:107)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
```

Is there a clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you also add related error.log lines?

Comment: "There is no error in the error log" that's not possible, unless the logging config changed. This is an NPE and it should most definitely be logged in your error.log. If it's not, you have a bigger problem than just the replication.

Comment: What is the AEM version? Also, it would be helpful to know JDK version and SO installed. Also, do you have the latest service pack installed?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out an indexing issue.

It looks like the index was contaminated while content migration from another server during the process the following workflows were disabled:

- com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.launcher.WorkflowLauncherImpl
- com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.launcher.WorkflowLauncherListener

By removing the index in /crx-quickstart/repository/index and restarted the instance, the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Do you recall which index was the concern?